# kdb/q How to use conditionals (if/else) in a function

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, kdb

I'm trying to see how I can change the value in a table based on its current state.
Currently, the isSelected column is either a 0 or 1, and I want to change its value to the other, but I don't know how to do that in kdb/q.

Here's what I'm trying to do in psuedocode:

```
fChangeBit[table]:
    if table[rowToFlip][isSelected] == 0:
        set table[rowToFlip][isSelected] = 1;
    else if table[rowToFlip][isSelected] == 1:
        set table[rowToFlip][isSelected] = 0;
    return table;
```

Is there any way to do the if/else if/else in q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the vector conditional operator: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/vector-conditional/.

This can be used within qSQL queries, so it would look like:

```
update a:?[a=1;0;1] from table
```

where `a` is the column you are flipping the values in, and if you want to perform the update in place simply add a leading backtick to table, IE `table.

You may also want to check out https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cond/ for some more info.

Comment: Thank you, this helps, but it looks like it edits that single row in the table, how do I get it to be saved to the table?

Comment: note that if you are worried about this row containing any non 0/1s (or maybe regardless of safety) then it would look like 

`update a:?[a=0;1;?[a=1;0;a]] from tab`

which will leave any non 0s/1s as they are.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. How do I do that edit for a single row in my table? For example, maybe it's the 5th row where I need to flip, can I use that script to update the whole table to include that changed 5th row?

Comment: Using the leading backtick on the table name in the update statement (like `table) will update the table in place i.e will save it to the table

Comment: Sorry I am a noob at q, but given the code above (`update a:?[a=0;1;?[a=1;0;a]] from "table`) where do I say that it's this one row to change the status of, and nothing else?

Comment: I'm thinking something like this, but it only updates that one row in my table: `update a,b,c, column:?[column=1;0;?[column=0;1;column]] from "table[randomRow]`

Comment: Don't worry, oh my apologies I had misunderstood the question for choosing the rows you'll want to add a where clause to your qSQL query so 
~~~
update column:?[column=1;0;?[column=0;1;column]] from `table where i in (0;1;3;4)
~~~

this will apply the changes in rows 1 2, 4 and 5 (i is a virtual column for indexing the table alternatively your where clause could be for when another column in your table has certain values it depends on how you know which rows you wish to change.  Sorry the formatting becomes a real pain trying to backtick the table lol

Comment: Also ignore what I said in that comment i deleted about needing to include the other columns in the update statement, I was mistaken

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

you can use the ? vector conditional operator: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/vector-conditional/

```
q) t: ([]id:til 10; isSelected: 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1)
q) show t
id isSelected
-------------
0  0
1  1
2  0
3  1
4  0
5  1
6  0
7  1
8  0
q)show update isSelected:?[isSelected=1; 0; 1] from t
id isSelected
-------------
0  1
1  0
2  1
3  0
4  1
5  0
6  1
7  0
8  1
9  0
```

in this case where you're just flipping 0's and 1's, you can also use the not operator:

```
q)show update not isSelected from t
id isSelected
-------------
0  1
1  0
2  1
3  0
4  1
5  0
6  1
7  0
8  1
9  0
```

Comment: Yes, I think the simple use of `not` is the cleaner solution here